# Destination of Team Foundation Server Databases

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010

In our company, we work under the Team Foundation server 2008. By default the databases destination is C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\DATA.

The problem is that the C drive is small and we are always running out of space.

I am thinking to move the databases from the C drive to D drive, but I am not sure what are the consequences of such action.

Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving the database to a different drive won't have any affect on how you access TFS through Visual Studio.  You can simply detach and re-attach the database files in a different location.  See [these instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190794.aspx) for doing so.

**Edit:** Note that there are quite a few databases that need to be moved.  Here's an [additional resource](http://adallow.wordpress.com/2009/04/01/moving-tfs-databases/) that you'll want to refer to as well.

Comment: Thank you for the additional resource

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to move them as you would move and other SQL database (probably best detaching, copying and re-attaching at their new location). I cannot think of any problems with moving them.